# Log4j rollover at certain time

Tags: time, configuration, log4j

I need to configure log4j to rollover new file only once a day at 11pm.
 
Is it possible to rollover file at certain time and not just every hour or at midnight?
I know that it can be configured to rollover each hour or each day, but that doesn't suit my case.

Thank you!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should add a cron trigger policy to your rolling file appender.
Take a look on [log4j docs](https://logging.apache.org/log4j/2.x/manual/appenders.html)